# Problem with last value of 'array' not changing when using 'for in' loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

```
let array = [1,2,3,3,3,4]

let dict = {}

for (let i in array){
    dict[array[i]] = 0
}

for (let i in array){
    if (array[i] in Object.keys(dict)){
        dict[array[i]]++
    }
}
console.log(dict)

// My intended value : { '1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 3, '4': 1 }
// Actual result value : { '1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 3, '4': 0 }
```

There is a difference between my intended result value and the actual result value (see comment above). What is the problem?

Comment: to add to the correct answer in @BenStephens's comment, you cannot use `in` operator to check if array has value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `Object.keys(dict)`, but simply just use `dict` as in `if (array[i] in dict){`

```js
let array = [1,2,3,3,3,4];

let dict = {};

for (let i in array){
    dict[array[i]] = 0;
}

for (let i in array){
    if (array[i] in dict){
        dict[array[i]]++;
    }
}


console.log(dict)
```

*Note*

If you wish to make the code less you can do `array.forEach(num => dict[num] = (dict[num] || 0) + 1);`

Comment: Thanks. 
What specifically is the difference between my code and your answer's code? What's the difference in how it works?

Comment: @Preamm (from looking at:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in ) In returns true if the thing you're comparing with has that property. `Object.keys(dict)` is an array so the properties are the array indexes. Try `2 in ['1', '2']` and `2 in ['1', '2', '3']`. The first one is false (the indexes only go up to 1) and the second is true (because it has index 2).

Comment: @BenStephens's comment is the correct answer, other answers are actually workarounds

Answer (score -1):

let array = [1,2,3,3,3,4];

let dict = {};

for (const element of array) {

dict[element] = (dict[element] || 0) + 1;

}

console.log(dict);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

well, you can simple use the exist or not in dict, method.

check this out:

```
    let array = [1,2,3,3,3,4]
    
    let dict = {}
    
    for (let i in array){
        if (!(array[i] in dict)){
            dict[array[i]] = 1
        }
        else if (array[i] in dict){
            dict[array[i]]++
        }
    }
    console.log(dict)
```